# How does _layout.svelte know if it's in the error page?

Tags: svelte, sapper

The `segment` variable in `_layout.svelte` is `undefined` for both the home page and error page. I want to render the page differently for these pages, but couldn't figure out a way in `_layout.svelte`.

Comment: Will the _error.svelte page work for rendering a different page for an error?

Comment: Sorry, no. the part being different lives in _layout.svelte

Answer (score 0):

As of version `Sapper 0.27.9` this isn't possible.

However, there is a work around.

Go into your project, and edit the file at this path

`[project-name]/node_modules/sapper/runtime/app.mjs`

Go to the `handle_error` function, and look for `const props = {...`

change the `segments: preloaded` key:value to `segments: ['_error']`

Now go to the `hydrate_target` function

change `const segments = page.path.split('/').filter(Boolean);` to

`const segments = page.path === '/' ? ['index'] : page.path.split('/').filter(Boolean);`

Once you do this, start your app with `npm run dev`, and the `segment` should now be `_error` or `index` instead of `undefined`, depending on the page you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Sapper 0.28.9` it is possible to use `$page.error` in `_layout.svelte`:

```js
<script>
  import { stores } from '@sapper/app';
  const { page } = stores();
</script>

{#if !$page.error}
  <!-- error pages sit outside of the default layout-->
  <slot />
{:else}
  <fancy-layout>
    <slot />
  </fancy-layout>
{/if}
```